# Amount and Indices of Skew Diagonals in n-dimensional structures

Tags: combinatorics, skew-symmetric-matrices

Suppose you have an $n ^ m$ matrix, in this example $3 ^ 2$.

Each of those will have a $1$ at the "start", then increase linearly.

$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}\right)$

The skew diagonals, going from top-left, in this example are  (in no particular order):

$\left(3\right)\\
\left(2,4\right)\\
\left(1,3,5\right)\\
\left(2,4\right)\\
\left(3\right)$

Is there a way to get these from some formula? For this example, to know that I have

- 1 Diagonal of size $3$, starting from $1$
- 2 Diagonals of size $2$, starting from $2$
- 2 Diagonals of size $1$, starting from $3$

Of course, it seems to get a bit more tricky as the dimension of the matrix increases. In the $3^3$ case, there is 3x $\left(3\right)$ and 3x $\left(3,6\right)$, for example.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you want. I think you can help by explaining why it is useful to you to count these things. Even if it is a complicated programming thing, context is essential.

Comment: Do you not understand what I want or do you not understand what I want it _for_? I tried to strip the problem of all the surrounding noise to represent the problem at its core.

Comment: Both. For example, in the $3^3$ case, two of the diagonals would be $(2,5)$ and $(3,6)$. Do you want to count those together, like "six diagonals of size $2$", or separately, like "three copies of $(2,5)$ and three copies of $(3,6)$"?  I understand you wanted to strip the context to make it easier to comprehend, but adding the motivation helps me confirm I am actually interpreting the problem correctly.

Comment: The latter: "Three copies of (2,5) and three copies of (3,6)" (and then all others, too). The actual problem is a bit detached from this, I don't think it would really help.